# Linked List of Linked Lists in Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I would like to know how to create a linked list of linked lists. Also, It would be helpful if the predefined `LinkedList` (class from Java) and its methods are used for defining and for other add, get, listIterating operations.

Comment: Its even ok, if i get code of user-defined linkedlist class with basic methods. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to comment on your post in this fashion.  You can edit your original question at any time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can put any object in a list, including another list.

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<YourClass>> list = new LinkedList<LinkedList<YourClass>>();
```

is a `LinkedList` of `LinkedList`s of `YourClass` objects. It can also be written in a simplified way [since Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html):

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<YourClass>> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

**Very simple examples of manipulating such a list:**

You then need to create each sublist, here adding a single sublist:

```
list.add(new LinkedList<YourClass>());
```

Then create the content objects:

```
list.get(sublistIndex).add(new YourClass());
```

You can then iterate over it like this (sublists' items are grouped by sublist):

```
for(LinkedList<YourClass> sublist : list) {
    for(YourClass o : sublist) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

If you want to add specific methods to this list of lists, you can create a subclass of `LinkedList` (or `List`, or any other `List` subclasses) or you can create a class with the list of lists as a field and add methods there to manipulate the list.

Comment: and how to iterate over this list of list ??

Comment: @roottraveller Added a simple example :) There are many ways this can be done, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Well i've done this code and i've got it right

```
          java.util.LinkedList mainlist = new java.util.LinkedList();

          java.util.LinkedList sublist1 = new java.util.LinkedList();
          sublist1.add(object1);
          sublist1.add(object2);
          sublist1.add(object3);

          java.util.LinkedList sublist2=new java.util.LinkedList();
          sublist2.add(1);
          sublist2.add(2);

          mainlist.add(sublist1);
          mainlist.add(sublist2);

          // To retrieve the sublist1 from mainlist...........
          java.util.LinkedList temp = (java.util.LinkedList)mainlist.get(0);
```

Here variable ***mainlist*** is **LinkedList of LinkedLists** and variable ***temp*** contains the value the first list stored i.e **sublist1**..

Answer (score 1):

You can even simplify access to the secondary lists, e.g. using

```
    final List<List<String>> lists = new LinkedList<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> get(final int index) {
            while (index >= size()) {
                add(new LinkedList<>());
            }
            return super.get(index);
        }
    };
```

This code automatically adds new `LinkedList`s to the outer list. With this code you can later easily add single values:

```
lists.get(2).add("Foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<YourClass>> yourList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<YourClass>>();
```

As the declaration. To add another linked list (to the end by default) you would do

```
yourList.add(new LinkedList<YourClass>());
```

To add an element to lets say the second linked list in the series:

```
yourList.get(1).add(new YourClass());
```